# Encountering 2 outputs combined in single input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a tuition calculator for students  and updating it to reflect the current year, in changing the year, every time the #variable option is selected to Variable (inherited code, not my choice of name) the output duplicates all of the fees. I've revised the functions, and code, where is this issue arising?

(my current version with issues: https://tarleton.edu/scripts/tuitioncal/default-trial.asp)
At first I thought it was a year issue, but after reading through previous documentation, I corrected it but issue is still arising.

I'm assuming that the issue arises here and that it runs through this if/else statement twice, though the information is not changing:

```
 $('input#submit').click(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear(); //Currently in the middle of 
    the academic year, so the adjustment had to be made.
    var adjustedYear = 0;
    var adjustmentForYear = 0;

    if ($('select#semester option:selected').hasClass('current-academic-year')){ adjustmentForYear = parseInt(-1); }

    else if ($('select#semester option:selected').hasClass('future-academic-year')) { adjustmentForYear = parseInt(0); }

    else if ($('select#semester option:selected').hasClass('last-year')) { adjustmentForYear = parseInt(-2); }

    if ($("select#variable option:selected").val() != "variable" || $('select#classification option:selected').val() == "4") 
    {
      //Handles ALL Guaranteed Tuition Plans and Graduate Plan
      adjustedYear = (parseInt($('select#semester option:selected').val()) + 
      adjustmentForYear - $('select#classification option:selected').val());
    }
    else
    { //Handles Variable Tuition Plans for Freshmen, Sophomores, Juniors, and Seniors
      adjustedYear = currentYear + adjustmentForYear;
    }
```

I expect a non duplicated output that includes University Services fee to be $91.66, but instead see University Services fee: $991.66 AND $117.89.

Comment: you should also include html content to question

Comment: Can you give a more precise example? What values would need to be input to get the output you've described. Your form is quite complex, on the real site. It's hard to reproduce your issue. Also "University Services Fee"...is that the "Fees" column on the site? I don't see that phrase anywhere. Please use precise terminology and instructions...don't forget we know nothing about your specific business area, we can only comment on the code. So please help us to navigate your application's jargon accurately. Thanks.

Comment: Also the code above seems a little incomplete - you calculate these adjustedYear and adjustmentForYear values....but then, in the sample you've shown, you don't do anything with them. Are these the fields which contain the wrong values? Again it's not clear a) how the code relates to the problem you're describing, or b) what happens to the values after they're calculated. It's very hard to link the code, the description, and the live demo together in a meaningful way. You need to edit your question so we can understand the situation properly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ADyson, I'll make some modifications to my question and include the inputs that lead me to get the duplicate information. I included only the code snip that I believed was causing the duplication.

Comment: Well it certainly helps to highlight the area where you believe the problem to exist, so please ensure your edit continues to do that. But without adequate contextual information it's impossible for us to understand how to reproduce the issue overall.